# If else statement using URL

Tags: python, django

HI I would like to ask for help on how to use URL in if statement

where

```
IF URL = detailsUrl
disable a div

ELSE
show div
```

for example this is my urls.py

```
 url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

I would like to know the correct if statement to be used to make this work thanks

Comment: Can you provide view here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request.path` in templates to control which divs are rendered:

```
{% url 'detail' 1 as details %}
{% if request.path == details %}
    <div>Details</div>
{% else %}
    <div>Else</div>
{% endif %}
```

Mind that you need to have `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `TEMPLATES` `options`.

Reference: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#templates).

Comment: Small improvement would be to use `{% url 'detail'  1 as details %}`

Comment: @Sayse indeed I missed this, thanks for the recommendation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url